# ASP.NET5 | MVC6 project hosting using 80 port

Tags: c#, hosting, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, port80

There is a `MVC 6 (beta 7)` project. I published it by the VisualStudio 2015 publish wizard to a local folder (on `Windows Server 2012`). Here is the `hosting.ini` file:

```
server=Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener
server.urls=http://localhost:80
```

Here is a command for starting the server in the `project.json`:

```
"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
```

I started the server by executing the `web.cmd` generated by a publish wizard from the local folder.

Site is working fine from a local machine (http://localhost).

**Ok, now is the most interesting**. I try to open it from an external computer and see

> HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Response headers are:

> Connection:close
>
> Content-Length:315
>
> Content-Type:text/html;
>
> charset=us-ascii Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

Ok, I found a similar problem with the `WAMP/Apache` hosting, for example [this](http://theandystratton.com/2012/wampapache-broken-from-microsoft-httpapi-2-0-using-port-80) and [this](http://www.passmark.com/forum/showthread.php?5146-WAMP-on-Server-2012-port-80-is-used-by-Server-Microsoft-HTTPAPI-2-0-Solved).

I tried to do the following:

1. Disabling the World Wide Web Publishing Service
2. Disabling the Web Deployment Agent Service
3. Making sure that there are not SQL Server Reporting Services and Branch Cache Service
4. Disabling IIS
5. Adding a rule for port 80 in a firewall
6. Killing all process from the `tasklist /M httpapi.dll` command by its `PID` (after that there is no listening of 80 port from the `netstat -ano` command) and then start application.

But it did not help.

*For note:* 
Here is a result of the `tasklist /M httpapi.dll` command after start the application after clause 6:

[image]

Here is a process with PID 1800:

[image]

What and why blocks 80-port?

How can I get around this?

Thank you!

Comment: With MVC 5, you had to run Visual Studio as Admin for ports in a certain range (Including 80). Have you tried that?

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed Yes, I always run it as Administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the issue is the bindings you have for the site. In your config you say:

```
server.urls=http://localhost:80
```

This means the site will only respond to you if you have the URL `http://localhost` in your browser window, however from an external URL you would use `http://192.168.100.100` for example. Try changing the URL to match that (obviously use your own IP address or machine name):

```
server.urls=http://192.168.100.100:80
```

I think you can also specify multiple URLs by separating them with either a semi colon or a comma:

```
server.urls=http://localhost:80;http://server:80;http://192.168.100.100:80
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you very much. It was so easy! :)